# Android Ad integration and ad image formats

Tags: android, admob, ads, millennial-media

Wondering if there are any android advertisement platform/SDK's that would let me pick the size for the ad? I have attached a screen shot of an app layout and I am interested in replacing one or two of the tiles with an Ad... Is there an android ad platform that you would recommend?

I have been digging into some of the ad sdk's and the closest I could find was the rectangle ad's offered by [millennial media](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-SDK/AndroidRectangleAds.html). Although I am not sure if they would let me pick an aspect ratio/size that is closest to their recommended aspect ratio of 1.2

I also looked at AdMob but it looks like only support banners or full page ads..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Admob does only offer banner or interstitial ads.